# Divide every value in the rows by the corresponding value in the column head in r

Tags: r

I need to divide values in the rows by the corresponding values in the column head and then get the sum of each row

I have this data as a csv file:

```
df <-
  read.table(text =
"Year    2    3   4   5   6   7   8
 1985    0   4   0   4   0   0   0
 1986    1   3   3   0   9   7   6
 1987    5   0   0   0   0   0   8
 1988    7   2   0   8   0   3   0
 1989    0   0   0   1   0   2   0"
             , check.names = FALSE)
```

I am looking for this results

```
Year    2   3   4   5   6   7   8     SUM
1985    0   1.3 0   0.8 0   0   0     2.13
1986    0.5 1  0.75 0  1.5  1  0.75   5.5
1987    2.5 0   0   0   0   0   1     3.5
1988    3.5 0.6 0   1.6 0   0.4 0     6.19
1989    0   0   0   0.2 0   0.2 0     0.49
```

Then I need to save the results as csv.

Comment: `df / as.numeric(names(df))[col(df)]` would work.  Then just add the other column with `rowsSums` and round.

Comment: @RichScriven I'm not sure if it would work this way.

Answer (score 1):

One approach, using `dplyr` just to clean up the code, is to use `apply` and convert the column names to numeric. Note that, because you changed the row.names to a column ("YEAR") we need to handle those separately. Here, I do it by removing that column with `df[ ,-1]` then adding it back at the end (here, with mutate, but you could do it separately as well).

```
apply(df[,-1], 1, function(x){
  x / as.numeric(colnames(df)[-1])
}) %>%
  t %>%
  addmargins(2) %>%
  data.frame(check.names = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(YEAR = df$YEAR) %>%
  select(YEAR, everything())
```

Alternatively, and probably overkill for this example (but perhaps useful more broadly) is to use `tidyr` to convert to long first, which gives some potentially more flexible options for both control and summarizing:

```
df %>%
  gather(head, val, -YEAR) %>%
  mutate(divided = val / as.numeric(head)) %>%
  select(-val) %>%
  spread(head, divided) %>%
  mutate(Sum = rowSums(.[ , -1]))
```

Both give the same values, in roughly similar formats.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this efficiently as follows:

```
m <- as.matrix(df[,-1])
m <- round(t(t(m)/m[1,]),2)
df[-1,-1] <- m[-1,]
df$SUM <- rowSums(df[,-1])

#    V1  V2   V3   V4  V5  V6   V7   V8   SUM
#1 Year 2.0 3.00 4.00 5.0 6.0 7.00 8.00 35.00
#2 1985 0.0 1.33 0.00 0.8 0.0 0.00 0.00  2.13
#3 1986 0.5 1.00 0.75 0.0 1.5 1.00 0.75  5.50
#4 1987 2.5 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.00 1.00  3.50
#5 1988 3.5 0.67 0.00 1.6 0.0 0.43 0.00  6.20
#6 1989 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.2 0.0 0.29 0.00  0.49
```

We convert `df` to matrix `m` in order to benefit from vectorized operations that can be done in matrix. Here is what is done:

1. Convert `df` to matrix `m` (exclude the first column)
2. Divide each row by the first row element-wise
3. Put the data in `m` back to `df`
4. Compute sums per row in `df`

So as to save it as `csv` file:

```
write.csv(file=fileName, x=df)
```